# PowerShell ISE open multiple tabs

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I'm new to PowerShell and just discovered PowerShell ISE (3.0). Previously I used three shortcuts for cmd-windows:

1. One for jboss to run server scripts
2. One for build scripts that needs JDK6
3. One for build scripts that needs JDK7

These shortcuts would open the windows at correct path and set JAVA_HOME.

Now I would like to create one shortcut that would open corresponding tabs in PowerShell ISE with appropriate names. I was thinking that I could manipulate $psISE.PowerShellTabs in a script, but I can only create new tabs and change names, I can't manage to change directories or variables as I like.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the invoke method to run code.

```
$NewTab = $psISE.PowerShellTabs.Add()
$NewTab.DisplayName = "NewTab"
sleep -m 160
$NewTab.Invoke({cd C:\ ; cls})
```

This will create a new tab, call it NewTab, wait for it to open, change the directory to C:\ and clear the output.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `$NewTab.Invoke({cd C:\ ; cls})`, and it seams that when I execute the three lines in a script I get an exception on the last line: "Cannot run script.", if I execute the last line separately it works

Comment: This appears to be a timing issue.  I needed to add in a `sleep -m 160` to make it work.  Anything less than that and the tab hasn't opened yet, so running code in it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Method provided by Mark is not always working correctly. You need to wait and check if your tab is ready, instead of assuming arbitrary delay.

```
$NewTab = $psISE.PowerShellTabs.Add()
$NewTab.DisplayName = "NewTab"

While (-not $NewTab.CanInvoke) {
    Start-Sleep -m 100
}

$NewTab.Invoke({cd C:\ ; cls})
```

Comment: It gets really funny when you try to add that to your profile (`psedit $profile`). New tabs are added infinitely .. Looking for a way around that.